# How to know the cpu utilisation of node process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpu-usage, cpu-speed

I tried it by using `top -pid 27045` which gives the output

[image]

Then calling an api which having decrypting some values,  looping over arrays in multiple time.

It leads to degrading the AWS instance.

I need to determine which process take these much of cpu utilisation.

How to know the cpu amount used for decryption process?
I am using `cryptr` npm.

I am doing some modification in array of objects using the loop.

Is there any way to know about cpu utilisation by loop?

I also tried https://github.com/davidmarkclements/0x project to generate flame-graphs. But does not showing the `cryptr` module.

Comment: I would suggest using chrome dev tools on the local to record CPU & memory utilizations.

Comment: Okay. Let me try this